# Navbar positioning left vs top

Tags: usability

I'm developing a web app and I'm wondering what is best for user experience: navbar on the left or the top of the page.

I'm looking on several CMS and generally they put the navbar on the left side, this would be the *admin* interface, but I'm not sure if it's the best practice, or why.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it dashboard?

Comment: @NB4 Yes it is a dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are Designing a **CMS** or may have a **Dash board** then it **better to go with the left side Navbar Design concept**, because its have, too much links(quick links) and easy to access in case you have too much data even if you scrolled too much and you are bottom of your page.

top navbar concept is best for landing pages and information related pages.

Answer (score 2):

For the **Admin Area** normally **trend** in market to follow **left side navigation.**

For the **front end view** you can go with **top navigation**

Answer (score 2):

If you have small numbers of nav links, you can put them on the top.
For example, this ux.stackexchange forum.

If you have a lot of nav links, you can categorize them to shortlist the number of immediate nav links and still put them on the top. For example, Amazon User's Menu Area
[image]

If the number is still big, you can put them on the left, like the typical CMS admin page that you have seen.

The strategy really depends on the content of your site. 
Big sites like Amazon will adopt a mixed strategy.
You can try several approaches and do usability testings to figure out which one works best for your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to place on the left side. By placing it on the left side it would be easy to scan the tabs. Secondly no constraint on the space.

Whereas in case of the top side there would more scanning required to view tabs i.e eye tracking would be more. Space is also a constraint.